# 10-year visa in old passport

Tags: visas, passport-renewals

My old US passport expires in October 2018. I have applied for a new passport. The 10-year visa to India expires in January 2019.

Can I travel with this visa if I travel in October 2018 and return in November 2018?

Answer (score -1):

According to my knowledge, as long as you can present both passports on exit it will be accepted.  My suggestion is that you contact the local embassy or consulate to verify this.